# Java String Explanation needed

Tags: java

**Hey can someone please explain this coding line by line?**

```
public boolean twoE(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'e')
            count++;
    }
    if (count == 2){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
 // this last if/else can be written simply as "return (count == 2);"
}
```

Comment: is there a particular part of it that you don't understand? the loop, the charAt() operation, or which?

Comment: What about it confuses you? Why don't you try looking up the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for methods you don't understand.

Comment: It obviously counts the number of 'e's and return `true` if the number of 'e's is 2 and `false` otherwise (fyi, the return statement should be `return count == 2`, not some superfluous if-else construct...oops didn't actually read the comment).

Comment: You need to identify a specific question about coding. Just posting some code and asking of someone can explain it to you is off-topic. Stack Overflow is a Q&A resource, not a help forum. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary of what this function does is that it returns a boolean (true or false) whether or not the String argument passed in contains exactly two lowercase `e` characters.

How it achieves this is as follows:

1. Initialize an empty count of 0
2. Loop through every character of the string
3. For each character, if the character is a lowercase `e`, add 1 to the counter
4. After you are done looping, check what the count was.
5. If the count was exactly 2, return true, otherwise, return false.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean twoE(String str) {
```

Declares method `twoE` that takes the argument `str` of type `String`.

```
 int count = 0;
```

Creates a variable named `count` of type `int` and initializes it to `0`.

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
```

Uses a `for` loop to iterate from 0 - the length of the string (`str.length()`).

```
if (str.charAt(i) == 'e') count++;
```

Checks if the the `i`th letter (`str.charAt(i)`) of `str` is a `'e'`. If so, increment the count.

```
if (count == 2) return true;
    return false;
```

If there were 2 'e's, then return `true`, otherwise, return `false`.

**Note** You might not have written this code, but if you did I have one suggestion. Change the last line to `return (count == 2);` to save space and make the meaning more clear.